# Mouse Event on stackPane JavaFX without children

Tags: listview, javafx, event-handling, mouseevent

Hello i tried to deselect listview items when mouse click on stackpane (father). I try this code but when user click on buttons (children of Stackpane) the event was triggerd anyway:

```
stackPane.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                listVisits.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            }
        });
```

How can i trigger only stackpane mouse event click?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0):

you do not need `MOUSE_PRESSED`. replace with `MOUSE_CLICKED`

```
stackPane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
     listVisits.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
});
```

Comment: I tried to replace `MOUSE_PRESSED` with `MOUSE_CLICKED` but after clicking the listview row remains selected only for a moment

Comment: This doesn't really address the issue. Any child of the `StackPane` not consuming the click event still clears the selection...

Answer (score 0):

You can easily tell the cases apart using the `pickResult` property of the `MouseEvent`. Note that in this case there is no need to use an event filter allowing the use of a event handler which results in a bit shorter code (that is of course unless you need to set this to another value).

```
stackPane.setOnMousePressed(evt -> {
    // only update selection, if the cursor doesn't hover a child
    if (evt.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode() == stackPane) {
        listVisits.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        evt.consume(); // don't pass the event to event handlers of ancestors (desired ?)
    }
});
```

Note that using an event handler you could consume the event for some children, if you want to just exclude some of the children from passing the event on to the `StackPane` instead of all of them. If you do this, checking the `pickResult` is no longer necessary:

```
eventBlockingChild.setOnMousePressed(MouseEvent::consume);
```